# Bang operator vs assert statements

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

In the code below, I'm casting away the nullability by using the bang operator.

```dart
void main() {
  String? foo;
  foo!.toLowerCase();
}
```

But when I use `assert` just before calling the function, I get an error.

```dart
void main() {
  String? foo;
  assert(foo != null);
  foo.toLowerCase(); // Error
}
```

Is bang operator not doing the same thing behind the scene?

**Note**: I'm not looking for a solution to how to make it work, there are many ways, even the flow statement ones, `if (foo == null) return;`

Comment: Asserts are not always being executed and can therefore not be used to guarantee anything: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert

Comment: `assert` only works in debug mode, hence they are not executed when the app is built for production. Meaning, you cannot use `assert` instead of the bang operator.

Comment: `assert(foo != null)` does not perform type promotion on `foo`.  See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36883.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adding this an answer instead of a comment.)

The point of `assert`s is that they can be disabled and that they will not incur any runtime penalty.  [It's been some matter of debate](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36883), but the current philosophy is that this means that `assert`s will not perform type promotion, so even if you do:

```dart
bool foo(Object object) {
  assert(object is String);

  // error: The getter 'isEmpty' isn't defined for the type 'Object' 
  return object.isEmpty;
}
```

For the same reason, `assert(someLocalVariable != null)` will not promote `someLocalVariable` to a non-nullable type:

```dart
bool bar(String? string) {
  assert(string != null);

  // error: The property 'isEmpty' can't be unconditionally accessed
  //        because the receiver can be null.
  return string.isEmpty;
}
```

As of Dart 2.12 with null-safety enabled, however, you can get the desired effect by just performing the cast directly.  That will promote the type and throw a runtime exception if the cast fails:

```dart
bool foo(Object object) {
  object as String;
  return object.isEmpty;
}

bool bar(String? string) {
  string!;
  return string.isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: If I know it well, is `string!` equivalent to `string as String`?

Comment: They're not exactly the same; they'll both throw `TypeError`s, but the error messages might be different.